# Is it possible to view change history of a Google shared calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I intend to create a common shared calendar to use in my group and I want to see the list of changes and their owners.

Is there a way to do so? I've tried on Google Calendar but I cannot find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: In that case, Google shared calendar is not suitable to me since any team member can modify my items and I can't know who did that - e.g. the group surely broken if someone delete everything!?